# Checking for overlapping characters in a wordsearch game

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, wordsearch

I am developing a wordsearch generator to learn c++ better and I am stuck on preventing non-overlapping words from overlapping, such as a side-to-side word writing over a letter in a top-down word.  Here is the code snippet:

```
else if (random_choice == 1 && random_word.size() <= 10-j && words_vector.size() != 0) {
    flag = true;
    for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
        if (wordsearch[i][j+x] != '0') {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag = true) {
        for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
            wordsearch[i][j] = random_word[x];
            j += 1;
        }
        j -= 1;
        words_found_vector.insert(words_found_vector.begin(),words_vector[random_word_number]);
        //words_vector.erase(words_vector.begin()+random_word_number);
    }
    else {
        wordsearch[i][j] = '1';
    }
}
```

What I have done was create a two dimensional array [10][11] filled with the 0 (zero) character so when I iterate through it all spaces are filled with 0 except for the 11th space in each line with a newline character to make a 10X10 grid.  In my else if loop, the first part already has a word chosen and it tests if the word will fit in its proper space by checking if a 0 is present.  If it runs into a non-zero character (such as if it runs into a letter from a top-down or diagonal word) the inner loop terminates, sets the boolean flag, and inputs a 1 (or any random letter) instead of the whole word.  What happens is that the whole word is inserted anyways and overwrites one letter from the top down word.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is the rest of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    const char* const a_to_z = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" ;

    int random_char;

    char wordsearch [10][11] = {0};

    bool flag;

    string words_array[] = {"CAT", "HELLO", "GOODBYE", "DOG", "BAT", "NEW", "SAY", "MAY", "DAY", "HAY"};
    vector<string> words_vector (words_array, words_array + sizeof(words_array) / sizeof(string));

    string words_found_array[] = {};
    vector<string> words_found_vector (words_found_array, words_found_array + sizeof(words_found_array) / sizeof(string));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
            int random_choice = rand() % 5;
            int random_word_number = rand() % words_vector.size();
            string random_word = words_vector[random_word_number];

            if (j == 10) {
                wordsearch[i][j] = '\n';
            }
            else if (random_choice == 1 && random_word.size() <= 10-j && words_vector.size() != 0) {
                flag = true;
                for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                    if (wordsearch[i][j+x] != '0') {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if (flag = true) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                        wordsearch[i][j] = random_word[x];
                        j += 1;
                    }
                    j -= 1;
                    words_found_vector.insert(words_found_vector.begin(),words_vector[random_word_number]);
                    //words_vector.erase(words_vector.begin()+random_word_number);
                }
                else {
                    wordsearch[i][j] = '1';
                }
            }
            else if (random_choice == 2 && random_word.size() <= 10-i && words_vector.size() != 0) {
                int temp_i = i;
                flag = true;
                for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                    if (wordsearch[i+x][j] != '0') {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag = true) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < random_word.size(); x++) {
                        wordsearch[i][j] = random_word[x];
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    i = temp_i;
                    words_found_vector.insert(words_found_vector.begin(),words_vector[random_word_number]);
                    //words_vector.erase(words_vector.begin()+random_word_number);
                }
                else {
                    wordsearch[i][j] = '1';
                }
            }
            else {
                int random_char = rand() % 26 + 0;
                wordsearch[i][j] = a_to_z[random_char];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                cout<<wordsearch[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout<<"Your words are:"<<endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < words_found_vector.size(); x++) {
        cout<<words_found_vector[x]<<endl;
    }
}
```

One more thing:

```
//words_vector.erase(words_vector.begin()+random_word_number);
```

crashes my program.  I think it is a scoping issue with this:

```
int random_choice = rand() % 5;
int random_word_number = rand() % words_vector.size();
string random_word = words_vector[random_word_number];
```

What I want to do is eventually have the user give me a list of words they want to search for and this function chooses some of them and presents it to the user when playing the game.  This not functioning correctly also causes duplicates to appear in the crossword and words-to-find-list.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error twice in your code:

```
if (flag = true)
```

That is *not* a condition, it's an assignment. It assigns `true` to `flag`, and the if-block will always execute. You need to make it a comparison condition by using `==`

```
if (flag == true)
```

A more common way to write that in C++ would be just

```
if (flag)
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  I did that and had to change up the code a bit to make it work for the == but it still does not prevent non-overlapping words from overlapping.  I'm redoing those sections though and see what I can come up with.  By any chance do you know whats wrong with my erase function for vectors? Inserting works though.

Comment: @user2671156 Your vector erase crashes because of the loop. It ends up removing everything from the vector, and then `int random_word_number = rand() % words_vector.size();` crashes because the size is 0, so a division by zero occurs.

Comment: I see the problem with the vector.  It totally slipped my mind that it was removing more words instead of one due to the loop.  Thanks! Also I solved my issue with overlapping words.  Since I initialized my 2D array with {0}, all places are filled with the NULL character, not zero.  So instead of if (wordsearch[i][j+x] != '0') {, it should be if (wordsearch[i][j+x] != '\0') {, where '0' becomes '\0'.  That in combination with flag == true makes it work fine now.  Thanks for the help.